# which is the external firewall in my scenario below?

Tags: iis, ftp, ip, firewall

I got a public IP from the ISP and  no port is blocked by the ISP.

My server running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Web Edition Trial is connected directly to the ISP. In other words, **I don't use a router between my server and the ISP.**

From IIS Manager, at the server level, I click `FTP Firewall Support` icon. It brings up the following

[image]

Based on my scenario above, my questions are

1. Which is the external firewall ? Is it the Windows built-in firewall?
2. What is the external IP address of Firewall ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in this scenario firewall support is also needed in case of using NAT, and not just firewalls.

Test is your servers IP address is a public one, or if your ISP uses NAT.
you can do this by browsing to a site like http://www.whatismyip.com/.

If the address is the same as the address you have on your server you probably don't need to enable firewall support. if they are different, supply the address you got from the site.

Note that your ISP may change your public IP address unless you specifically requested a permanent address.

Comment: @Ophir: My IP is a static public one and not behind a NAT.